# How to position a drawable inside an android button?

Tags: java, android, xml

I have some design issues in Android.
I want to make some buttons, with a drawable inside, and place the drawable on top of my text. I succeeded, in a sense, to do that, which give me the following interface.

[image: interface]

To talk about the code, i'm using a TableLayout, in which i've put two TableRow, designed as it follows :

```
<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/row1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/actu"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/mon_actu"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_shopping_cart_black_48dp"
        android:paddingTop="100dp"
        android:drawablePadding="-130dp"
        android:gravity="center"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/commerce"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_shopping_cart_black_48dp"
        android:paddingTop="100dp"
        android:drawablePadding="-130dp"
        android:text="@string/mes_commerces"
        android:gravity="center" />
</TableRow>
```

This is the final result i want to have, but when i launch it on my own phone, all the icon are on the text, hiding it. I guess the problem comes from the values of my paddingTop, and drawablePadding values, because it's absolute values, and the resolution is different according to the model.

What can i do to solve this issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must not have static and negative values for responsive design which support multiple device with different resolutions.

Instead of you can use `TableLayout` with `TableRow` and `LinearLayout.`

Try This Out:

```
<TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_shopping_cart_black_48dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Hello World" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_shopping_cart_black_48dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Hello World" />
            </LinearLayout>

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_shopping_cart_black_48dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Hello World" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_shopping_cart_black_48dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Hello World" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
```

This will be supported in all device with different resolutions and height-width.

Comment: @Jikar if you want onClick, you just need to set onClick on linearLayout. additionally you can have selector on linearLayout.
- Happy Coding.